# Find all array permutations of splitting a string in C+++

Tags: c++, string, split, permutation

I have a string of numbers that I'd like to split into all possible combinations (the order of letters must be remain fixed), so that:

```
data = "12479"
```

Output

```
combs = [[1, 2479], [1, 2, 479], [1, 24, 79] ...etc]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: This reads like a home work question.  Either ask this as a generic algorithms question, or look through the algorithm header file to see if any of the functions can be conscripted into your purpose.  If you need help with C++, specifically, then you should be more precise with your question.  Is data a a stl string or char *, do you want the result to be array or vector of int or did you want string or char *?

Comment: What is your code so far? This site is not intended for doing people homework. Doing homework is essential to learn.

Comment: Are you interested in non-recursive algorithm based on this ?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65546565/algorithm-for-joining-bubbles   Imagine each of the blue bubbles being one character of your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recursive algorithm is straight forward:

```
combinations(data)
  if size(data) == 0 return []
  if size(data) == 1 return [ data ]
  return
     [ head(data) ] + combinations(tail(data)) +
     [ head(data) + head(combinations(tail(data))) + tail(combinations(tail(data)))
```

The first two return statement are base cases.  The 3rd return statement either split the first element off or doesn't.  Note that +, head or tail operate either on arrays or strings depending on context.