# Algorithm for joining bubbles

Tags: c

Is there a faster (or cleaner) algorithm for joining bubbles of water as shown below ?

[image: Bubbles]
The animated example above depicts closing 4 arbitrary gaps between 8 bubbles.

I came up with this ugly code, which takes an `arrayK` of indexes of the gaps between the bubbles (this array is guaranteed to be sorted and to be of length `K`), "joins" `N` bubbles and outputs the lengths of the joined bubbles.
It works but I am not satisfied with it. Is there a faster and/or cleaner code that outputs the same data when given the same input?

```
void JoinBubbles(const unsigned int* const arrayK, unsigned int K, unsigned int N)  
{   //ArrayK is of size K and is sorted. Obviously K must be less than N and all elements of the array must be less than N-2.
    unsigned int h, i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < arrayK[0]; i++)
        printf("1.");

    for (h = 0; h < K; h++)
    {
        for (i = h + 1; (i < K) && (arrayK[i - 1] == arrayK[i] - 1); i++);
        printf("%d,", i - h + 1);
        for (j = arrayK[i - 1] + 2; (i < K) && (j < arrayK[i]); j++)
            printf("1.");
        h = i - 1;
    }

    for (j = arrayK[K - 1] + 2; (j < N + 1); j++)
        printf("1,");
    
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all `i` from 0 to N-1, there are two possibilities:

- `i` represents the end of a bubble. In this case, print the size of the bubble, and reset the size to 1.
- `i` is inside of a bubble (because `i` matches the next entry in the K array). In this case, increment the size of the bubble, and update the index into the K array.

The code looks like this:

```
void JoinBubbles(const unsigned int* const arrayK, unsigned int K, unsigned int N)
{
    int k = 0;
    int bubble = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (k >= K || i < arrayK[k]) {
            printf("%d.", bubble);
            bubble = 1;
        } else {
            bubble++;
            k++;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: What is the theory behind the variable `k` (lowercase) ?

Comment: @GeorgeRobinson `k` is the index into `arrayK`. So `arrayK[k]` is the location of the next gap that will be closed. The condition `k >= K` occurs when the end of `arrayK` has been reached, i.e. all gaps that need to be closed have been closed. The condition `i < arrayK[k]` occurs when `i` is still to the left of the next gap (`arrayK[k]` is the next gap to be closed). If **either** condition is met, we're at the end of a bubble. If **neither** condition is met, we've arrived at a gap than needs to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Use a disjoint-set union.

See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/disjoint-set-data-structures/.

Lets say you join bubbles at index 0, then merge 0 and 1.

Additionally, maintain an array `size`. Initialize this to 1, then for each merge, add the size of the two sets being merged.

At the end, simply sweep from 1 to N, and output the size of bubbles which have not been outputted before (could be implemented by using a bool array to record which sets have been visited)

With path compression speedup, this will run in `O(n)` memory and time complexity.

Implementation is quite simple and  is left as an exercise as a reader. (my coding style is too ugly)